# Regex: What is the right regex to use in order to match all proxy servers?

Tags: ruby, bash, templates, puppet

I'm writing a puppet template for our proxies farms.

We have data centers in Amsterdam, Singapore, NY etc..
The proxies in each geo-location are named accordingly, for example:
Proxies in Singapore are named sgproxy01-10 , proxies in Amsterdam are named ams2proxy01-30, etc...

While writing this template which will eventually affect all servers in my company, I'd like to write an "IF Statement" which will add specific lines only to proxy servers with names matching the pattern i'm trying to set.

```
<% if @hostname =~ /^sgproxy\d+/ -%>
if [ "$(cat $LBMEMFILE)" = "0" ]; then
echo -e "\e[35m Membeship in LB:        Yes"
elif [ "$(cat $LBMEMFILE)" = "2" ]; then
echo -e "\e[35m Membeship in LB:        No $LISTMEMFILE"
<% end -%>
```

The regex I'm trying to set is in the first line:

"<% if @hostname =~ **/^sgproxy\d+/** -%>"

With the current configuration all servers which their hostname starts with sgproxy and then any other digit afterwards will get these lines.

I want to change the regex so it will affect all servers which include proxy\d+ .

I tried the following regex's:

```
^??proxy\d+
^..proxy\d+
^*proxy\d+
```

None works.

Can you please help me find the correct regex to match all servers with the word "proxy" in their hostnames?

Comment: You've already done it...: `/proxy\d+/`

Comment: What does `@hostname` contain? How do you know it doesn't work? Here's a [rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/cms1i3DT2e) that shows your regexp working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Puppet uses the same regex as Ruby](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#regular-expressions)

`/proxy\d+/` should work fine, [Rubular](http://rubular.com) is pretty good for quickly checking Ruby regexs. Like so:

[image: Screenshot of Rubular]

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to match the whole line, you might match the part only. That said,

```
/proxy\d+/
```

will do the trick. While you still want to be more precise:

```
# whether proxies have only letters, digits and underscores in prefix
/\A\w+?proxy\d+/
```

or

```
# whether proxies can not contain spaces in names 
/\A\S+?proxy\d+/
```

Sidenote: it’s generally better to use `\A` match for the beginning of string rather that `^`.